# Dplyr create new columns based on nested data in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, nested

I have data that looks like this:

[image: disease_data]

I want to convert it to data that looks like this:

[image: modified disease data]

The column "Type" is a category or sub category and the column "Number" tells me how many of the sub-categories that follow belong to that category. The sub-categories themselves may or may not be nested. So for example, the first category is "Rare liver disease" and there are 7 sub-categories under it, but the sub-category "Autoimmune hepatitis" has 3 sub-categories under it as defined by the "Number" column. What I want to do is create two new columns called "Level1" and "Level2". The column "Level1" takes the "Name" (which is the entry in the first row in the Name column) and fill that value in all rows until the next instance of the type CAT. Level2 is filled in with the value in the Name column unless the number is greater than 0, in which case the value from the Name column is filled down to the subsequent n rows, where n is defined by the value in the Number column.

The data is

```
disorder_list <- structure(list(Name = c("Rare liver disease", "Autoimmune hepatitis", 
"Autoimmune hepatitis type 1", "Autoimmune hepatitis type 2", 
"Autoimmune hepatitis type 3", "Hepatic fibrosis", "Fulminant viral hepatitis", 
"Cirrhotic cardiomyopathy", "Syndromic diarrhea", "Pseudotumor of the liver", 
"Fibrohistiocytic inflammatory pseudotumor of the liver", "Lymphoplasmacytic inflammatory pseudotumor of the liver", 
"Idiopathic cirrhosis", "hypoplasia syndrome", "fatty liver", 
"hepatosteatosis", "hepatosteatosis - typea", "hepatosteatosis - typeb", 
"pancreatic dysplasia", "cholangitis", "cholangitis type1", "cholangitis type2", 
"cholangitis type3"), Type = c("CAT", "D", "d", "d", "d", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "I", "i", "i", "F", "CAT", "D", "B", "b", "b", 
"D", "D", "d", "d", "d"), Number = c(7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0), Level1 = c("Rare liver disease", 
"Rare liver disease", "Rare liver disease", "Rare liver disease", 
"Rare liver disease", "Rare liver disease", "Rare liver disease", 
"Rare liver disease", "Rare liver disease", "Rare liver disease", 
"Rare liver disease", "Rare liver disease", "Rare liver disease", 
"hypoplasia syndrome", "hypoplasia syndrome", "hypoplasia syndrome", 
"hypoplasia syndrome", "hypoplasia syndrome", "hypoplasia syndrome", 
"hypoplasia syndrome", "hypoplasia syndrome", "hypoplasia syndrome", 
"hypoplasia syndrome"), LEVEL2 = c("Rare liver disease", "Autoimmune hepatitis", 
"Autoimmune hepatitis", "Autoimmune hepatitis", "Autoimmune hepatitis", 
"Hepatic fibrosis", "Fulminant viral hepatitis", "Cirrhotic cardiomyopathy", 
"Syndromic diarrhea", "Pseudotumor of the liver", "Pseudotumor of the liver", 
"Pseudotumor of the liver", "Idiopathic cirrhosis", "hypoplasia syndrome", 
"fatty liver", "hepatosteatosis", "hepatosteatosis", "hepatosteatosis", 
"pancreatic dysplasia", "cholangitis", "cholangitis", "cholangitis", 
"cholangitis")), row.names = c(NA, -23L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Number = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Level1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), LEVEL2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000001a6e3be9630>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I managed to add the column "Level1" as follows:

```
category <- disorder_list %>% 
  mutate(category_num1 = cumsum(Type %in% "CAT")) %>% 
  group_by(category_num1) %>% 
  mutate(Level1 = Name[1])
```

What I am struggling with is adding the column Level2. Would love any suggestions to make progress on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's always the case that the subcategories are flagged by a lower case letter, then you can use the same logic as the calculation for `Level 1`, e.g. `disorder_list %>%
 mutate(subid = cumsum(grepl("[[:upper:]]", Type))) %>% group_by(subid) %>% mutate(L2 = first(Name)) %>% ungroup()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was a contrived example and the subcategories have no information that can be used to create a flag. I was thinking  perhaps of filling the Number column down the appropriate number of rows but can’t think of a good way to do that.

Comment: Try `disorder_list %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(Number > 0)) %>% mutate(LEVEL2 = coalesce(rep(Name, Number + (Number > 0))[1:n()], Name)) %>% ungroup()`